# Lognormal curve fitting equation

Tags: matlab, statistics, curve-fitting, distribution

I have run into a very peculiar problem. It might seem silly to a lot of you. But I am in dire need of a way out. I am analyzing sets of high-speed images with **MATLAB**. The image of interest (https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4h26y3mvpao8m6/sample.png?dl=0) is an average of 3000 images (background subtracted). As shown in the picture, I am reading the pixel intensities/values along columns. As this is a laser beam, the shape or beam profile away from the wall has the shape of a Gaussian distribution. As I approach to the wall (the brightest part at the right of the image) because of some effect the shape is turning into one like a log-normal distribution. In this spreadsheet (https://www.dropbox.com/s/yeim06a5cq3iqg8/sample.xlsx?dl=0) I have pasted the raw intensities as I read thru from point A to point B. The column D has the raw intensities and the column E has the values achieved with a '**sgolay**' fit of the column D values. If I plot these it pretty much has the shape of a lognormal distribution. I can get the mu and sigma with the '**lognfit**' or '**fitdist**' functions. Now the question is what is the equation [expressed as a function of pixel location (x) or the pixel intensity (y)] of the fitted '*lognormal curve*' that could be used to recreate the fitted curve? Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The lognfit extracts the mu and the sigma of the lognormal distribution. The mu is the mean of logarithmic values and sigma the standard deviation of logarithmic values. You can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution for the shape of the function given mu and sigma.
[image: Function definition logrnomal]

With logrnd(mu,sigma) you can generate samples from the same distribution:
https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognrnd.html?searchHighlight=lognrnd&s_tid=srchtitle_lognrnd_1